# How to resolve Cannot modify header information warninig in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am getting the below warning when i tried to do redirection.please help me to solve this fix this.

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\cakePHP\cake\libs\debugger.php:673) [CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line 742]

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if there is any output before calling `header()` function. The most common and mostly "invisible" mistake is having whitespaces at the beginning or the end of one or more of your files. Make sure there are none before opening `<?php` or after closing `?>` tags.

Additionally you may also try:

1. Configure your editor to trim
   trailing whitespaces before saving
   the file.
2. Pre-commit hooks in the SCM of your
   choice.
3. The tip from Tomba (see comment
   below), if you cannot pinpoint the
   location of your trouble.

Comment: Another reader suggested on my original answer: *To avoid such problems, you may safely skip `?>` at the end of your PHP files.*

Comment: I found this script useful for removing whitespace from php files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943727/find-all-files-with-blank-or-ws-at-bof-or-eof

Comment: install the dubug kit and then do `cake whitespace`

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
```

It's `helpful.write ob_start();` in controller